# how to get data from persistent Storage in EhCache - java

Tags: java, android, caching, ehcache

I have used the `persistent` storage of `Ehcache` for caching and storing data.
Here's the Code I got:

```
import org.ehcache.PersistentCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder.persistence;
import static org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder;

public class home {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //  Creating Persistent Cache
        PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager =
                newCacheManagerBuilder()
                        .with(persistence("/tmp/tempProjectCache"))
                        .withCache("test-cache",
                                newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                        String.class, String.class,
                                        newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                                .heap(1, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                                                .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB)
                                                .disk(2, MemoryUnit.MB, true)
                                )
                        ).build(true);

        org.ehcache.Cache persistantCacheStorage = persistentCacheManager.getCache("test-cache", String.class, String.class);
        persistantCacheStorage.put("name1","prince");
        persistantCacheStorage.put("name2","steven");
        System.out.println(persistantCacheStorage.get("name1"));
    }

}
```

`Output` Got:

```
prince
```

It worked great. The data got into the disk. 
Next time, I removed this one line from the Source Code

```
persistantCacheStorage.put("name1","prince");
```

from the code and run the code. 
Now the `Output` was

```
null
```

Since it is `persistent` storage, the data already got on the disk. why it is not getting the already stored data from the disk. 
I don't know what I am making wrong. If it was recreating the Folder with Files, then how to avoid this and make use of old cache data in `EHCache` I am a newbie in `java`. Help me with some solutions.